# Regex: select words that are smaller then 4 characters

Tags: regex

I would like to select words that are smaller then 4 characters, and add a * at the beginning and end. Example:

```
Hello my friend? 
How did you like my car? 
I guess that my opinion about your car is favorable.
```

So I want to replace the above with this:

```
Hello *my* friend? 
*How* *did* *you* like *my* *car*? 
*I* guess that *my* opinion about your car *is* favorable.
```

I'm using this search pattern: `(\w{3,})`. But it does the opposite. Thus, selecting words greater than 3 characters.

Comment: You need `\b\w{1,3}\b`. Or `\b[a-zA-Z]{1,3}\b`, `\b\p{L}{1,3}\b`...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is ok but my substitution is: `*$1*`, and it doesn't work with that.

Comment: `{3,}` means "3 characters or more", for "3 characters or less" you should've used `{,3}`, but you also need to make sure you don't select 3 characters in the middle of a word, so use the pattern provided by @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Your substitution can be adjusted to use a backreference to the whole match, `$0` or `$&` or `&`. You never need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group when substituting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I changed it to `(\b\w{1,3}\b)`, and it gave the result I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b\w{1,3}\b
```

\b is word boundary, it makes sure you don't match part of a larger word.

You can replace with `*$&*` - `$&` is a replaced with the whole match.

Comment: I needed this: `(\b\w{1,3}\b)`. Please change it.

Comment: You needed the parenthesis only because you replaced with `*$1*`, if you had replaced with `*$0*` you wouldn't need the parenthesis. Since there is nothing in your question regarding grouping or how you intend to do this replacement, the answer is correct.

Comment: This is a millionth dupe, why answer it again and again?

Comment: @Victor - Not sure. I was on mobile and it made sense at the time. By the way, I don't think you've picked a good duplicate - that one was more about unicode.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You referred to a PHP question. But this is a more general question. Plus, I couldn't find it that fast in my search engine. So I guess it's ok to ask.

Comment: @Julian PHP regex is PCRE and this is a default regex engine assumed for questions tagged with `regex`. I basically copied the title and found  a lot of next to identical questions.